# How to initialize yaml parser/loader/dumper for a class

Tags: python, class, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I want to initialize yaml with following parameters

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
...
def null_representer(self, data):
    return self.represent_scalar(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:null', u'null')

yaml = YAML()
yaml.representer.ignore_aliases = lambda *data: True
yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
yaml.representer.add_representer(type(None), null_representer)
```

I wanted to know if there's a way I can initialize yaml like this to use in my class

```
class A:
   def __init__(self):
        self._yaml = (the yaml I initialized)
```

For example, python logging module has this fucntion -

```
import logging

def init_logging():
    log = logging.getLogger()
    log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    sh = logging.StreamHandler()
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    sh.setFormatter(formatter)
    log.addHandler(sh)

class A:
   def __init__(self):
        self._log = logging.getLogger('A')
```

Comment: If you have `ruamel.yaml` specific question make sure to add the tag [tag:ruamel.yaml]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `YAML()` instance to be the global one that you already initialised, and class `A` is anywhere in the same file, you can just do

```
def __init__(self):
    self._yaml = yaml
```

as long as you don't make an instance of `A` before `yaml` is assigned to.

If you have the class `A` in a different file, just import `yaml` from the Python file, just like you import `getLogger`. E.g. if the first code block is in `myyaml.py`:

```
from util.myyaml import yaml
```

Make sure you have (an empty) `__init__.py` files in the subdirectory `util`

Of course you can also give an instance of class `A` its own `YAML()` instance:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

def null_representer(self, data):
    return self.represent_scalar(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:null', u'null')

class A:
   def __init__(self):
       self.yaml.load(.....)

   @property
   def yaml(self):
       try:
           return self._yaml
       except AttributeError:
           pass
       self._yaml = yaml = YAML()
       yaml.representer.ignore_aliases = lambda *data: True
       yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)
       yaml.preserve_quotes = True
       yaml.representer.add_representer(type(None), null_representer)
       return yaml
```

This is the way I usually do things. If `self.yaml` is not used in the `__init__()`, the instantiation of `YAML()` will be delayed until you first use it, which might speed up your program startup.